# How to find variance of a vector?

Tags: least-squares, covariance

I am given a set of measurements:

$\tilde{y_1}=x+v_1$

$\tilde{y_2}=x+v_2$

Where $v$'s are random variables with $E\{v_1\}=E\{v_2\}=E\{v_1v_2\}=0, E\{v_1^2\}=a, E\{v_2^2\}=b$.
A least squares solution with basis matrix $H=[1\:1]^T$ and weighting matrix $W=0.5I$ is:

$\tilde{x}=(H^TWH)^{-1}H^TW\tilde{y}=0.5\tilde{y_1}+0.5\tilde{y_2}$

I need to find the variance of the error, i.e. $E\{(x-\tilde{x})^2\}$ but $x$ is a 2x1 vector while $\tilde{x}$ is a scalar, so I am not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to my understanding about the problem you have understand the problem incorrectly. **$x$, itself is a random variable, not a random vector**, and $\bar{y}=[\bar{y_1}\space \space \space   \bar{y_2}]^T$, in which each of the $\bar{y_i}$, is itself a random variable since $x$ is a random variable (not a random vector). If you proceed in this way then you have:

$E[(x-\bar{x})^2]=E[(x-0.5(2x+v_1+v_2))^2]=E[(-0.5(v_1+v_2))^2]=0.25E[v_1^2+v_2^2+2v_1v_2]=0.25(E[v_1^2]+E[v_2^2]+2E[v_1v_2])=\frac{a+b}{4}$

Comment: OK, so what if we had $x_1$ and $x_2$ instead? What would have changed? In that case, $x$ is a random vector...

Comment: In that case v1 and v2 must be random vector which will result that y1 and y2 are random vector as well.

Comment: Your question is similar to this case: We have K different transmitters, in which the transmitter tx_i transmits the signal x_i. Hence the transmitted signal is a vector in which each of its elements is x_i. In this case, we have a noise vector, in which its i(th) element affect the i(th) transmitted signal, and in the receiver we have K different signal, and we wanna to detect them.

Comment: So in that case: $\tilde{y_1}=x_1+v_1$ , $\tilde{y_2}=x_2+v_2$ and then each should be considered separately  and H will simply be a scalar --1. Is that right?

Comment: Yes .I think it works in this manner